# Why is there disagreement on the number of surfaces of the human heart?

Tags: human-anatomy, cardiology

I am finding that some state that there are 5 and some that say that there are 3.

For example, "Cardiology: An Integrated Approach" that was published in 2018 states that

> There are 3 surfaces of the heart: anterior, inferior, and posterior

[Radiopedia](https://radiopaedia.org/articles/heart?lang=us), [Teach Me Anatomy](https://teachmeanatomy.info/thorax/organs/heart/borders-sinuses-sulci/), and others state that there are 5.

Why is there this difference? What exactly is a surface?

Comment: Hmm. Curious what answers you get. Anecdotally, I've studied cardiac (and especially coronary) anatomy extensively and have never seen these "surfaces" described. Seems silly to me and not related to the actually relevant anatomy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heart **surfaces** are not clearly anatomically defined but arbitrary determined in the context of the heart *orientation,* that is the relation of the heart to other organs. Different sources mention 3 or 5 heart surfaces and there seems to be no "official" agreement about this.

Most sources ([Dartmouth College](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~humananatomy/part_4/chapter_23.html), [Gray's Anatomy for Students 2004...](https://books.google.com/books?id=xoJUDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA199&lpg=PA199&dq=Gray%27s%20Anatomy%20for%20Students%20%22heart%20surfaces%22&source=bl&ots=U98TJG8d6s&sig=ACfU3U1ZD6DOUDnNm8ksKnTldIYLOIQkZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY2vfGk8nnAhVa6qYKHcKbCBcQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Gray's%20Anatomy%20for%20Students%20%22heart%20surfaces%22&f=false)) agree about at least 3 surfaces:

- Anterior (or sternocostal)
- Inferior (or diaphragmatic)
- Left pulmonary

Many sources ([TeachMeAnatomy](https://teachmeanatomy.info/thorax/organs/heart/borders-sinuses-sulci/), [KenHub](https://www.kenhub.com/en/library/anatomy/heart)...) mention additional 2 surfaces:

- Posterior (or base)
- Right pulmonary

The reasons for disagreement:

- The heart *base* may not be considered a distinct surface (as in the picture).
- The *right pulmonary* and *anterior (sternocostal)* surface are often considered one surface.

[image]

*Picture: Heart surfaces (source: [Echo Class 101](http://www.echoclass101.com/?tag=heart-anatomy))*